# Does Open Graph work only for users with enabled timeline?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, facebook-timeline

I'm building an Open Graph App that should be able to publish, retrieve, and delete custom actions and custom objects in/from user profiles. I followed the step-by-step instructions and tried to publish action to my profile. I kept getting error #100 until I enabled timeline on my profile and then it worked. 
My questions: does open graph work only for users with enabled timeline? what about all other facebook users who haven't enabled timeline? Is there another way to publish, retrieve and delete custom actions/objects which support all users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open Graph **Actions** are only created/published for users who have timeline and allowed `publish_actions` permission to your Application.

**BTW**, [OpenGraph](http://ogp.me) is a protocol not Facebook functionality:

> The Open Graph protocol enables any web page to become a rich object in a social graph. For instance, this is used on Facebook to allow any web page to have the same functionality as any other object on Facebook.
>
> The Open Graph protocol was originally created at Facebook and is inspired by [Dublin Core](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dublin_Core), [link-rel canonical](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html), [Microformats](http://microformats.org/), and [RDFa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RDFa).
>
> It is currently being consumed by Facebook ([see their documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/)), Google ([see their documentation](https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/+1button/#plus-snippet)), and [mixi](http://developer.mixi.co.jp/en/connect/mixi_plugin/mixi_check/spec_mixi_check/). It is being published by IMDb, Microsoft, NHL, Posterous, Rotten Tomatoes, TIME, Yelp, and many many others.